# Samsung series 9 is bricked. What can I do?

Tags: laptop

I had ubuntu running on my samsung series 9. (NP900X4C-A01FR). While I had a few problems, it was running fine. The 2 major issues I had were that my wifi driver was unstable, and a system update caused my system to be unable to boot (I think it was a problem between lightdm and my graphic drivers). But everytime I was able to reinstall.

Now, after a reboot, the only thing that happens when I press the power button is that the blue led turns on, and nothing else (no fans). The bios menu doesn't show up. If I plug in an external monitor, I get no signal.

I've tried a full discharge and start, full charge and start with and without power cord plugged in. I've tried holding the power button for 15secs. But nothing does it. Plugging in a bootable USB does nothing.

While "on", the computer heats up quite a bit. Pressing the power button for about 5 seconds turns the computer off.

I wonder if I can open it without cancelling the warranty (to backup some files).
Is there anything I can do besides returning it to the repair center ?

Comment: Opening it will generally void the warranty.

Comment: If you still *have* warranty, I'd RMA the device. Especially if a simple update caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: Opening the HD bay shouldn't void the warranty.

Comment: The HD bay is the part at the back that is maintained with screws ?